# snake case for column names in phantom-dsl

Tags: phantom-dsl

Im trying to use this library for an existing application that already have records in cassandra and it table columns are written in snake case. Is there a way to have my phantom model objects in snake case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look [**here**](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/blob/64d954c7058203310521f75e699ef3c5fe172699/docs/src/main/mdoc/basics/tables.md#the-name-of-the-table-can-be-controlled-using-namingstrategy), at the official documentation.

```
import com.outworkers.phantom.NamingStrategy.SnakeCase.caseSensitive
import com.outworkers.phantom.NamingStrategy.SnakeCase.caseInsensitive
```

There is also a test suite that might be of help, but you need to import this in every file where you define tables. Tests are [**here**](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/blob/64d954c7058203310521f75e699ef3c5fe172699/phantom-dsl/src/test/scala/com/outworkers/phantom/tables/NamingStrategyTests.scala).

Comment: Thanks @flavian, However, the documentation says ***These control only the tableName, not the columns or anything else.***

Answer (score 2):

Just override column name:

```scala
abstract class User extends Table[...] {

   object lastName extends StringColumn {
       override val name: String = "last_name"
   }

}
```